# Openpyxl: extract column letter(s) from columns object

Tags: python, formatting, openpyxl

I am trying to apply conditional formatting on a per-column basis for all columns in the openpyxl columns object. To do this, I want to extract the column letter for each column tuple that I iterate through.

I am specifically trying to find a way of getting the column letter out of the `col` tuple here:

```
column_letter = get_column_letter(col)
```

...within this function:

```
def create_formatted_table(wb, worksheets: list, file_name):
    existing_tables = [
        wb[sheetname].tables.items()[0][0]
        for sheetname in wb.sheetnames
        if len(wb[sheetname].tables.items()) > 0
    ]
    worksheets = [
        worksheet for worksheet in worksheets if worksheet not in existing_tables
    ]
    if worksheets:
        for ws in worksheets:
            worksheet = wb[ws]
            for col in worksheet.columns:
                column_letter = get_column_letter(col)
                min_row = col[0].row
                max_row = col[-1].row
                rule = ColorScaleRule(start_type='min', start_color=Color(rgb="FFB499"), 
                                    end_type='max', end_color=Color(rgb="99FFC3"))  
                worksheet.conditional_formatting.add(f"{column_letter}{min_row}:{column_letter}{max_row}", rule),    
            wb.save(file_name)
    else:
        print("Nothing")
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: As you state **col** is a tuple of cells. We expect there will be at least 1 element therefore col[0] will be valid which contains the column number and column index. So **column_letter = get_column_letter(col[0].col_idx)** or **column_letter = get_column_letter(col[0].column)** will provide the column letter.

Comment: It's worth noting that the length of each column willl be the same as all are derived from `ws.max_row`. And, you can **always** use a `CellRange` object to calculate dimensions programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the library, but a quick way that I could figure out is the following:

```
rule = ColorScaleRule(start_type='min', start_color=Color(rgb="FFB499"), 
                                end_type='max', end_color=Color(rgb="99FFC3"))  
for col in worksheet.columns:
    start_of_col = f"{col[0].column_letter}1"
    end_of_col = f"{col[0].column_letter}{len(col)}
    ws.conditional_formatting.add(f"{start_of_col}:{end_of_col}", rule)
```

Comment: Thank you! With a few minor tweaks, your answer worked for me. This was the final forloop I used:

           for col in worksheet.columns:
                start_of_col = f"{col[0].column_letter}1"
                print(start_of_col)
                end_of_col = f"{col[0].column_letter}{len(col)}"
                print(end_of_col)
                rule = ColorScaleRule(start_type='min', start_color=Color(rgb="FFB499"), 
                    end_type='max', end_color=Color(rgb="68BDFF")) 
                worksheet.conditional_formatting.add(f"{start_of_col}:{end_of_col}", rule)

Answer (score 0):

Building on @AlduCor's suggestion, this is the final forloop that I used within the function:

```
     for col in worksheet.columns:
            start_of_col = f"{col[0].column_letter}1"
            end_of_col = f"{col[0].column_letter}{len(col)}"
            rule = ColorScaleRule(start_type='min', start_color=Color(rgb="FFB499"), 
                end_type='max', end_color=Color(rgb="68BDFF")) 
            worksheet.conditional_formatting.add(f"{start_of_col}:{end_of_col}", rule)enter code here
```